# How to select random record from mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, select, random, google-bigquery

I need to select say 2000000 records at random from a very large database. I looked at previous questions. So please do not mark this question as duplicate. I need clarification. Most answers suggest using `ORDER BY RAND()` function. So my query will be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT no
FROM table
WHERE name != "null"
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2000000;
```

I want each record to be selected at random. I am not sure if I understand the `ORDER BY RAND()` effect here. But I am afraid it will select a random record, say 3498 and will continue selection from there, say, the next records will be: 3499, 3500, 3501, etc.
I want each recor to be random, not to start the order from a random record.

How can I select 2000000 random record where each record is selected at random? Can you simplify what exactly `ORDER BY RAND()` does?

Note that I use Google BigQuery so the performance issue should not be a big problem here. I just want to achieve the requirement of selecting random 2000000 records.

Comment: I think you are using BigQuery and not MySQL. Try to make that clear please

Comment: I am using MySQL queries in BigQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT x
FROM T
ORDER BY RAND()
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT x
FROM (
  SELECT x, RAND() AS r
  FROM T
)
ORDER BY r
```

The query generates a random value for each row, then uses that random value to order the rows. If you include a limit:

```
SELECT x
FROM T
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

This randomly selects 10 rows from the table.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be sure, my posted query will select 2000000 random records from table `table` where name has a value for a name (i.e. not null)?

Comment: also, if I'm querying 5 million records using `ORDER BY RAND()` is this still good method with large number of records?

Comment: You need to use `name IS NOT NULL` to look for non-null names. Yes, the same technique is valid for larger limits.

Comment: The database owner have a field say what I call it here `name' which either contains a string or `null`. I see the `null` written with small letters like what I use. So I think they entered "null" in the field. I am not sure though if MYSQL can put null with small letters or leave it empty. But that's what I see. However, I think my query return not `null` at the end. Does this still seem to cause any issue? If you see anything wrong plz do let me know.

Comment: You asked about selecting random rows, and I answered that question. If you have a different question about null handling, submit a new question.