# How to select 1 row each condition

Tags: mysql, sql

[Input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suS0r.png):

| npost_id | mid | like_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | t4 | 3 |
| 21 | t11 | 2 |
| 30 | t16 | 2 |
| 31 | t16 | 2 |
| 32 | t18 | 2 |

I want the post_id that received the most likes per one person.

I need to pick only one row with satisfying several conditions: Max(like_count), per 1 id (Can be duplicated), npost_id (primary key)

Here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT npost_id, mid, like_count 
FROM feed
WHERE (mid, like_count) IN (SELECT mid, MAX(like_count) 
                            FROM feed
                            GROUP BY mid)
```

I can't think of anything other than that query.

Comment: Avoid using images to share data and queries. Double check that information between image and updated post match. If anything differs, update your post accordingly.

Comment: Can you share your expected output with respect to the input table?

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: That query returns 2 row where mid = t16.
I want to return any npost_id if same like_count.

Comment: "*I want to return any npost_id*" conflicts with "*query returns 2 row*". Are you looking for a comma-separated valued field?

Comment: If rows have different IDs, but the two columns(like_count and mid) have the same value, return any ID is okay.

Comment: When you want _any_ row, that could mean that you want a [random row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52907120/how-to-select-random-record-from-mysql-database). There is always to possibility to [LIMIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html#:~:text=The%20LIMIT%20clause%20can%20be%20used%20to%20constrain%20the%20number%20of%20rows%20returned%20by%20the%20SELECT%20statement) it to only 1 record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, one option to retrieve only one row for each combination of <mid, like_count> is to use the [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) window function, which allows you to assign a ranking value for each combination of <mid, like_count> (a partition). In order to get only one element for each of these, it's sufficient to filter out rows that have ranking bigger than 1 (the rows that have repeated <mid, like_count> values).

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY mid, like_count ORDER BY npost_id) AS rn
    FROM tab
)
SELECT npost_id, mid, like_count
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/khzaHyempUdxMAjBdUjh75/0).

---

In MySQL 5.7, you can instead aggregate on the two different combination of <mid, like_count> and take the smaller value for the npost_id field (given that you are willing to accept any npost_id value for the partition).

```
SELECT MIN(npost_id) AS npost_id, 
       mid, 
       like_count
FROM tab
GROUP BY mid, like_count
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/khzaHyempUdxMAjBdUjh75/1).